# Crystal Report fields displaying as XXXXXXXX (all fields)

Tags: crystal-reports

For some reason, all of my crystal reports are displaying all of the fields as 'XXXXXX' in the Design tab. This happens to every report I open. Did I turn on some option by mistake? Has this happened to anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

resolved. I accidentally unchecked the 'Show field names' option.